# Create an array of protocols with constrained associated types

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

This is a basic example of creating an array of protocols with associated types using type erasure:

```
protocol ProtocolA {
    associatedtype T

    func doSomething() -> T
}

struct AnyProtocolA<T>: ProtocolA {
    private let _doSomething: (() -> T)

    init<U: ProtocolA>(someProtocolA: U) where U.T == T {
        _doSomething = someProtocolA.doSomething
    }

    func doSomething() -> T {
        return _doSomething()
    }
}
```

Creating an array of them isn't hard:

```
let x: [AnyProtocolA<Any>] = []
```

Is there any way way I can create an array of protocols which have associated types **that are constrained**? This is what I have tried:

```
protocol Validateable {
    // I removed the functions and properties here to omit unreleveant code.
}

protocol ProtocolA {
    associatedtype T: Validateable

    func doSomething() -> T
}

struct AnyProtocolA<T: Validateable>: ProtocolA {
    private let _doSomething: (() -> T)

    init<U: ProtocolA>(someProtocolA: U) where U.T == T {
        _doSomething = someProtocolA.doSomething
    }

    func doSomething() -> T {
        return _doSomething()
    }
}
```

It compiles! But didn't it defeated the chance of creating an array of AnyProtocolA's now? Now I can't use type Any as a placeholder in my array.

How do I create an array of **AnyProtocolA**'s which has a constrained associated type? Is it even possible? This won't work since `Any` ofcourse doesn't conform to `Validateable`:

```
let x: [AnyProtocolA<Any>] = []
```

Extending Any can't be done:

```
extension Any: Validateable {} // Non nominal type error
```

Edit: 
I think I already found it, just type erasure the protocol Validateable as well:

```
protocol Validateable {
    // I removed the functions and properties here to omit unreleveant code.
}

protocol ProtocolA {
    associatedtype T: Validateable

    func doSomething() -> T
}

struct AnyProtocolA<T: Validateable>: ProtocolA {
    private let _doSomething: (() -> T)

    init<U: ProtocolA>(someProtocolA: U) where U.T == T {
        _doSomething = someProtocolA.doSomething
    }

    func doSomething() -> T {
        return _doSomething()
    }
}

struct AnyValidateable<T>: Validateable {}
```

Now I can use it as:

```
let x: [AnyProtocolA<AnyValidateable<Any>>] = []
```

Any answers that are better are always welcome :)

Comment: This feels like you've gone down the wrong road with protocols when you meant to use generic structs instead. The point of a PAT is to be able to attach generic methods to it. It's almost never in order to pass it to something else, and definitely not to store it. If you find yourself type-erasing everything, then you just wanted structs (or possibly just functions) in the first place and the protocols aren't pulling any weight. Also, if you're making `AnyValidatable<Any>`, you're almost certainly on the wrong road as well. Structs are not covariant in Swift, so `S<Any>` is always suspect.

Comment: (9 out of 10 times, I've found that your `x` above should have been `let x: [() -> Int]` or something like that.